# Using TDirect2DCanvas with Font Awesome Icons

Tags: delphi, gdi, direct2d

I'm writing an application with Delphi XE 10.2 that uses the **Direct2D canvas** and the **Font Awesome icons**.
The GDI canvas is correctly displayed, while the Direct2d canvas displays alphanumeric characters, but not the icons (Hexcode >= $f000). In their place the classic rectangle is displayed.
Can someone tell me the reason?
Thanks, Enzo

This is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  D2DCanvas: TDirect2DCanvas;
  Ch: Char;
begin
  Ch := Char($F4BA);
  Canvas.Font.Assign(Self.Font);
  Canvas.Font.Name := 'Font Awesome 5 Free Solid';
  Canvas.Font.Color := clHotLight;

  D2DCanvas := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(Canvas, Rect(0, 0, Width, Height));
  try
    D2DCanvas.Font.Assign(Self.Font);
    D2DCanvas.Font.Name := 'Font Awesome 5 Free Solid';
    D2DCanvas.Font.Color := clHotLight;
    D2DCanvas.BeginDraw;
    try
      D2DCanvas.TextOut(10, 50,  '(Direct2D): ' + Ch);
    finally
      D2DCanvas.EndDraw;
    end;
  finally
    D2DCanvas.Free;
  end;
  Canvas.TextOut(10, 150, '(GDI): ' + Ch);
end;
```

[image: with this result]

Comment: Direct2D has no builtin ability to display text. First make sure your font is rendered with DirectWrite correctly.

Comment: Assign some nonsense to TDirect2DCanvas.Font.Name and see if you get the same.